# Retail component of imported good in GDP?

Tags: gdp

If I buy a bottle of French wine at a wine shop - how does this add to GDP?

The imported (wholesale) bottle of wine does not count towards GDP; but the markup from the import price that I pay to the retailer does count towards GDP, right?

Comment: You may want to review the concept of GDP. Imports do count (negatively).

Comment: Yes, I didn't really say otherwise.

Comment: GDP is value of all final goods and services; so imports *do not* count. In the formula, I they do count negatively, because they are included in, among others, consumption. So GDP = G + C + I - net imports. If the bottle of wine in the shop is 20 and the importer paid 10, then the contribution to GDP is C - I = $20 - $10 = $10. I.e. the markup. So I haven't forgotten about the formula, but still my question is: is this right?